# When using ElasticSearch scroll api, can I skip to page n?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pagination, iterator

I'm using the elasticsearch scroll api. In some cases I'd like to return the hits on page n without returning the previous pages' hits. I believe this should be like an iterator. So I'd like to just pass the iterator through the first few pages, but then actually return the hits of the n-th page.

My current code is

```
initial_request = client.search(index = index, doc_type = doc_type, body = q, scroll = str(wait_time) + 'm', search_type = 'scan', size = size) 

sid = initial_request['_scroll_id'] ## scroll id
total_hits = initial_request['hits']['total'] ## how many results there are. 
scroll_size = total_hits ## set this to a positive value initially

while scroll_size > 0:

    p += 1
    print "\t\t Scrolling to page %s ..." %p

    page = client.scroll(scroll_id = sid, scroll = str(wait_time) + 'm')

    sid = page['_scroll_id'] # Update the scroll ID
    scroll_size = len(page["hits"]["hits"]) ## no. of hits returned on this page
    ## then code to do stuff w/ that page's hits.
```

but the `page = client.scroll(...)` actually sends the hits for that page back to my local machine. I'd like to just `pass` on the first n pages, then start sending the pages' hits after that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: that was 5 years ago. i simply don't know/remember

Comment: Did you remember?